# Check existence of element in list of elements

Tags: matlab, list, contain

In Python one can do something like this

```
the_weather_is = 'sunshiny'

bad_mood = {'dreary', 'drizzly', 'flawy', 'blustery', 'thundery'}

if the_weather_is in bad_mood:
    print 'Stay at home...'
else:
    print 'All fine...'
```

How would the MATLAB equivalent look like, i. e. have a list of strings (options) and check if `string` is in `list`?

Actually I don't even know, what one can use as list in MATLAB. CellArrays?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`bad_mood` is not a `list`, it's a [cell array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html).

You could use [`ismember` function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) to check if `the_weather_is` is in a `bad_mood` cell array:

```
ismember(the_weather_is, bad_mood)
```

---

Alternative solution (**from [Benoit_11's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25447249/1202461)**) is to use [`strcmp` function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcmp.html), combined with [`any` function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/any.html):

```
any(strcmp(the_weather_is, bad_mood))
```

`strcmp` compares `the_weather_is` with each string of `bad_mood` cell array and returns a logical array. `any` checks that returned logical array contain at least one `true` value.

Comment: +1 You mean "to check if `the_weather_is` is in `bad_mood` cell array

Comment: That's most readable somehow. `any(strcmp(the_weather_is, bad_mood))` apparently also works and it's faster, but the answer has been deleted

Comment: @embert added it as an alternative solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can use strcmp to check whether the_weather_is is part of the cell array bad_mood:

```
the_weather_is = 'sunshiny';

bad_mood = {'dreary', 'drizzly', 'flawy', 'blustery', 'thundery'};


if any(strcmp((bad_mood),the_weather_is))
    disp( 'Stay at home...')
else
    disp( 'All fine...')

end
```

Comment: Oh shooot I forgot the "any" before strcmp; it was in my command window but forgot to past it in my answer sorry